What evidence exists for the historical name of Kuwohi Mountain (formerly Clingmans Dome)?
Recently in the United States, The U.S. Board of Geographic Names approved changing the official name of Clingmans Dome to Kuwohi. For those unfamiliar, this mountain sits in the Great Smoky Mountains National Park, in the Appalachian Mountain range, and is a popular tourist attraction.
The name "Clingmans Dome" is attributed to an 1859 survey by Arnold Henry Guyot. According to recent media, the name Kuwohi is attributed to a Cherokee name for the mountain that pre-dated Guyot's survey. In this article by a local news network, Lavita Hill, identified as a tribal member of the Eastern Band of Cherokee Indians, states:

“From that point, we went to work, mainly through research, and
learned that Clingmans Dome was actually named Kuwohi before it was
ever Clingmans Dome,” Hill said. “It wasn’t changed to Clingmans Dome
until 1859, but for all of the period before that, it was Kuwohi. We
were fortunate to find references to Kuwohi, going back several
hundreds of years and therefore, it’s factual, that this was the true
name of the mountain.”

What evidence exists for a name for the mountain prior to 1859? Ideally, a suitable answer would contain link(s) to a digitized historical record, but if there is no digitized record available, an account of the type of record used to factualize the name of the Mountain would be sufficient (e.g. the written accounts of settler-X, the recorded oral traditions of tribe-Y, etc.).

The written source material we can access is from an ethnology done by James Mooney in 1891, The Sacred Formulas of the Cherokees, Volume 7. The Cherokee names of four mountains in the area are related in a traditional song called the bear song. Mooney's description of the song mentions Kuwahi a couple of times (emphasis mine):

The song consists of four verses followed by a short recitation. Each verse begins with a loud prolonged He+! and ends with Yoho'+! uttered in the same manner. Hayuya'haniwă' has no meaning. Tsistu'yi, Kuwă'hĭ, Uyâ'‘yĕ, and Gâte'kwâ'hĭ are four mountains, in each of which the bears have a townhouse and hold a dance before going into their dens for the winter. The first three named are high peaks in the Smoky Mountains, on the Tennessee line, in the neighborhood of Clingman's Dome and Mount Guyot. The fourth is southeast of Franklin, North Carolina, toward the South Carolina line, and may be identical with Fodderstack Mountain. In Kuwahi dwells the great bear chief and doctor, in whose magic bath the wounded bears are restored to health. They are said to originate or be conceived in the mountains named, because these are their headquarters. The "good black things" referred to in the recitation are the bears.

This records what beforehand would have been oral tradition. (Check @T.E.D.s answer for expertise on how long that oral tradition might entail)

FWIW, I only added an answer because my comments on this one were getting ridiculous to try to keep wedging into comments. This answer seems closer to the information the OQ was asking for.

I note that Kuwohi is very close to Currahee which is claimed to be from a Cherokee word pronounced as "quu-wa-hi" (basically the same as in the quote above). Currahee is about 2 hours drive south from Clingman/Kuwohi. Not sure the significance this has in the conversation and have no clue whether this has been addressed by the experts.

@Yorik - I'd be careful with that kind of thing without looking deeper into it. Living near the Cherokee Nation as I do, I know of several place names around here that sound rather similar to the English-speaker. Tulsa (formerly Tallasi), Tulahasse (compare with Tallahassee, FL), Tullahoma, Tahlequah, Talala, Talihena, Talimena, Taloga, Tamaha, Tonkawa. Different languages may favor sound combinations that stick out like a sore thumb in English.

I thought I addressed that by claiming total ignorance., but I agree with you. Just wondering. Wikipedia gives a Cherokee spelling which differs in the 1st glyph from the "Kuwohi". Again, am totally ignorant of the basics..

It says there was a mountain in that area that was called Kuwă'hĭ, but it doesn't say that Clingman's Dome is Kuwă'hĭ, just that the named mountains are in that area. Compare to Gâte'kwâ'hĭ which is described as "may be identical with Fodderstack Mountain". I'm of course not saying that Kuwă'hĭ isn't the same as Clingman's Dome, just that this specific text doesn't tell us that it is. Maybe there are other records which are more specific.

I think there's more evidence we have from linguistics. That of course isn't of the same quality as written proof, but that kind of evidence is good enough to be going on with when we are studying history in the Eastern Hemisphere and the written record runs low, so it ought to be good enough for us here in North America too.
First off, place names for natural features tend to be some of the most ancient words in a language. Often they even predate the language (or at least the language being in that area), and were taken from the people who lived there before the present residents. For instance, some place names in England are so old we don't even know what language they are from (which means quite possibly not even Indo-European).
So if that's the word residents were documented using in 1891, its a good bet it was being used a long time before then. I mean a long loooong time. This is why wiping out a traditional place name is practically a crime against history.
There's another linguistic principle that when you have a language family where one branch is spread out over a wide area, while the rest are all concentrated in one small area, that usually indicates that the small area is the proto-language's original homeland. For instance, here's a map of the Austronesian language family. This is a family with 10 branches, 9 of which are found on the small island of Taiwan, the rest spread out over about about 1/5 of the earth's surface. Based on this principle, its assumed that language family's ancient homeland (the home of proto-Austronesian) was Taiwan. That is what you will see in history books.

So let's look at what we know about Cherokee. The Cherokee language alone constitutes one of the 2 main branches of the Iroquoian language family. The other branch has all the remaining Iroquoian languages, much more closely related (and therefore more temporally close) to each other than any are to Cherokee, spread out northward clear into the St. Laurence valley in Canada.

This indicates a high likelihood of the entire Iroquoian linguistic family's ancient origin 3.5-4 thousand years ago being either in the historic Cherokee linguistic area, or somewhere quite near to it. Put these two linguistic inferences together, and we come up with the fact that there's a good chance the Cherokee word for that natural feature is at least 3,500 years old. To be clear, we are talking earlier than 1,500 BC here.
Or to put another way the name "Kuwohi" (ᎫᏬᎯ), with religious significance to the Cherokee people, likely predates the vast majority of the events depicted in The Bible, the Torah, The Koran, and the Rig Veda.

Caveat: Languages can be quite malleable over time. While the origin of "Kuwohi" might well be 3500 old, the word itself might have been quite different back then. For Germanic languages like English we know there have been vowel shifts (such as English vowel diphthongization in the 14th century) along with other changes. E.g. when scribes fixed the spelling of "knight" in the 11th century, they accurately recorded what they heard at the time, namely /ˈknixt/, which is quite different from our modern /naɪt/

@njuffa - Quite. Its probably reasonable to assume Cherokee is as different from  proto-Iroquoian as Mohawk and Cherokee are from each other (or perhaps half as different, considering they would have independently drifted in mostly different directions). Still, that mostly means the pronunciation may have changed some. As mentioned in the answer, place names themselves are quite durable.
